# Texture not showing on whole mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

This object seems not to have a correct normal arranging of the handle; the light-grey parts of the handle are supposed to be just like the wooden parts. Anyway I can correct them? I tried using different UV mapping options, but to no avail.

[image: UV mapped mesh in edit mode]

Comment: looks like the material is not assigned correctly : select the handle in edit mode and assign the material

Comment: Looks like you didn't assign wood material to those parts

Comment: Yes, looks like all the faces weren't assigned. But even after assigning, the texturing remains the same.

Comment: Check the UV if the faces are unwrapped, the problem may be if the vertices of those faces are in the same location.

Comment: All UV faces are unwrapped. Locations are distinct in the UV mapping.

Comment: try the usual suspect : in edit mode, select all and Ctrl+N

Comment: @Razzoriel isn't that just the reflection ,change the view angle and see if it change ?

Comment: i don't think so : see the square grey faces on the handle. The blade has the same problem btw

Comment: Recalculate Normals, right? I did before texturing for those pictures. Did it again; no dice.

Comment: upload you blend file then

Comment: I did, the view angle doesn't change the problem. It has the same issue when importing to Unity.

Comment: The file is here: http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/beardedaxe

Comment: the texture is missing but i think it comes from it, the unwrapping seems ok but some islands make me think about the grey shape

Comment: Texture: http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/beardedaxetexturefinal4

Comment: Its the alpha on the texture that rendered as grey color, and the UVs are not properly located on the texture.

Comment: UV has been scaled and moved, this messed up the texture placement

Comment: So, I should fix the texture and place it more closely on the UV? I used the Smart UV, 0.6 space between islands.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks Bithur and everyone who helped me up on this one!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UV map has been scaled and/or moved from it's original location.
[image]
You'll have to fix this manually, selecting all, scaling up a bit (1.3) for the most part. Then you have to fix each island 1 by 1, scaling and moving them to fit the image texture.

To easily select an island, put your cursor on it and press <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: This worked perfectly! End results were great, thanks again everyone! ![in game image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M74AW.jpg)

Comment: @PGmath no need to be in face mode in UV editing to select islands. This would be the case to select them on the mesh itself.